# I can't understand why can't Haskell deduce this type

Tags: haskell

I was trying to implement the filterM function using foldr, but receiving an error which I can't understand why.

my implementation (It is just for understanding, I know i should use do notation...):

```
filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> (m Bool)) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM f list = foldr foldFn (return []) list
    where 
        foldFn :: (Monad m) => a -> m [a] -> m [a]
        foldFn x acc = let 
            m = f x
            in acc >>= 
                \l -> m >>= 
                    \b -> (if b == True then return (x:l) else return l)
```

I Get the following error

```
Could not deduce (a ~ a1)
from the context (Monad m)
  bound by the type signature for
             filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
  at wadler.hs:124:12-55
or from (Monad m1)
  bound by the type signature for
             ff :: Monad m1 => a1 -> m1 [a1] -> m1 [a1]
  at wadler.hs:127:23-54
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
      at wadler.hs:124:12
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for ff :: Monad m1 => a1 -> m1 [a1] -> m1 [a1]
       at wadler.hs:127:23
In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
In the expression: f x
In an equation for `m': m = f x
```

I don't get why type a can't be deduced since foldr has type `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code?  I don't have `xs` in scope.

Comment: You shouldn't add the type signature to the local function if you are using the variables introduced by the outer patterns. If you want to do that you *must* use `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and quantify over the variables in the outer signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that you meant

```
filterM f list = foldr foldFn (return []) list
```

rather than `xs` at the end, so I'll assume that going forward.

The problem you're experiencing here is that the type variables in `foldFn`'s type signature is completely separate from type variables in `filterM`'s type signature.  It's really equivalent to saying

```
filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> (m Bool)) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM f list = foldr foldFn (return []) list
    where 
        foldFn :: (Monad m1) => a1 -> m1 [a1] -> m1 [a1]
        foldFn x acc = let 
            m = f x
            in acc >>= 
                \l -> m >>= 
                    \b -> (if b == True then return (x:l) else return l)
```

But, you use `f` in the definition of `foldFn`, which says that `m1` has to be the exact same as the `m` from above.  You don't want the type of `foldFn` to work on any `Monad`, only the `Monad` that `f` is using.  This is a subtle difference and a difficult one to spot at first.  It also applies to the difference between `a` and `b` in these two signatures.  What you can do is simply remove the type signature for `foldFn` and GHC can correctly infer the type of `foldFn`, but in cases where this doesn't work, you can use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.  I would not recommend using it in this case, but there are times when it's really useful or even necessary:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

filterM :: forall m a. (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM f = foldr foldFn (return [])
    where
        foldFn :: (Monad m) => a -> m [a] -> m [a]
        foldFn x acc = do
            l <- acc
            b <- f x
            return (if b then x:l else l)
```

And now the `m` and `a` in both type signatures refer to the same type variables.  I've also let [`hlint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) tell me some improvements that could be made to your code, such as moving the `return` out of the `if` statement on the last line, using `do` notation for `foldFn`, and eta-reducing `filterM` to make the `list` argument implicit, as well as removing some unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: I disagree; I would *always* recommend using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. Being able to give a type signature to local definitions (and, in fact being able to make that type signature about as specific as possible) is an immense aid to writing and understanding code.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` also allows type signatures on pattern variables, which can help you get started specifying types, and get better error messages from the type checker, even if you don't understand the type of the whole function. I see this as a special breed of extension—one that's useful for both newbies and advanced users.

Comment: @dfeuer In this case, it's possible to have a local type signature without using `ScopedTypeVariables`, you just have to pass in `f` as an extra argument to `foldFn` so that `foldFn` isn't a closure, [see here](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/db3c9e4a85340fbeba34).  I usually prefer this style anyway, if I later find I need to re-use `foldFn`, I have fewer changes to make in order to do so.

Comment: @dfeuer I will admit that `ScopedTypeVariables` can be useful for that purpose, but I know that it was an extension that confused me when I was a beginner with the `forall` syntax, and so being able to write code without it is useful when trying to convey an idea to a beginner who is unfamiliar with the syntax.